# JSONpath filter expression to return boolean

Tags: jsonpath

Problem:
I want to get `boolean` value `true` if the the `Array` features in the `json` contains `test1`

Example:

```
{
  "features": [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
  ],
  "name": "David"
}
```

For the above json, result should be `true`.

Comment: please show us what you have done so we could help you

Comment: Currently with the below jsonpath, I am getting result as test1.


$.features[?(@=='test1')]